# How to convert PHP variable value to boolean and use in jquery setting

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to pass values from option panel to use them on jQuery setting value everything working except `true` or `false`  SO How can I convert it or use it right way.

What I am trying where `$offers_animation_type = true`  its return `true` but not working as like if direct write `true` or `false` in the option value.

```
$("#Ticker").breakingNews({
    effect      :"slide-v",
    autoplay    :<?php echo $offers_animation_type;?>,
    timer       :<?php echo $offers_animation_change;?>,
    color       :"turquoise",
    border      :true
});
```

But it should be like

```
$("#Ticker").breakingNews({
    effect      :"slide-v",
    autoplay    :true,
    timer       :3000,
    color       :"turquoise",
    border      :true
});
```

Comment: you should never have PHP inside JS (and vice versa). It's a bad practice that can lead to unexpected behaviour

Answer (score 2):

In PHP printing `true` will result 1, but printing `false` will not print anything. So when the value was `false`, you broke the JS code. (`autoplay:,`)

```
$("#Ticker").breakingNews({
    effect      :"slide-v",
    autoplay    :<?php echo $offers_animation_type ? "true" : "false";?>,
    timer       :<?php echo $offers_animation_change;?>,
    color       :"turquoise",
    border      :true
});
```

Comment: I have added fixes on how I convert it using json encode.

Answer (score 1):

you can use ternary operator in php like this

```
    $("#Ticker").breakingNews({
    effect      :"slide-v",
    autoplay    :<?php echo ($offers_animation_type): 'true'? 'false'; ?>,
    timer       :<?php echo ($offers_animation_change): 'true'? 'false'; ?>,
    color       :"turquoise",
    border      :true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#Ticker").breakingNews({
   effect      :"slide-v",
   autoplay    :<?=(isset($offers_animation_type) && !empty($offers_animation_type))? 'true' : 'false'; ?>,
   timer       :<?=(isset($offers_animation_change) && !empty($offers_animation_change))? $offers_animation_change : 3000; ?>,
   color       :"turquoise",
   border      :true
 });
```